# Dialog.endConversationAction ConfirmPrompt

Tags: botframework

I'm considering giving users of our bot the ability to abort in the middle of a dialog making use of the endConversationAction.

I'm using a confirmPrompt because the interaction up to the point they cancel can be quite involved.

Unfortunately it seems like if they answer "no" to the "Are you sure?" confirmPrompt, that "no" response is fed back as an input to whatever the previous prompt was.

As an example, if the user had been presented with a numbered list of choices and responds with the word that triggers the endConversationAction, they're presented with an "Are you sure?" question.  Answering "no" I get "I didn't understand, please choose an option from the list."

This seems silly.  Is there a known way around it?

Comment: Please share the code you are using for the confirmPrompt and the prompt with list of choices.

Comment: `bot.dialog('booking', require('./booking')).triggerAction({
            // matches: /^make.*appt/i
            matches: 'BookAppointment',
            intentThreshold: 0.40
        })
        .endConversationAction(
            "endBooking", "Ok, no appointment made.",
            {
                matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^quit$|^nevermind$/i,
                confirmPrompt: "This will abandon your appointment. Are you sure?"
            }
        ); `

Behavior happens whether I'm at a choice prompt a text prompt or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it was the botbuilder package.

I duplicated your example bot and even enhanced it to more closely match mine.  It always worked.

Then following my hunch I copied the simplified bot code into my app.js and commented out everything else.  Essentially running it with my node_modules packages.  Suddenly it didn't work.

So then I went back to the working simplified bot and swapped in the botbuilder folder from my bot.  That broke it.  Even though in theory they were the same version.

Something got dorked somewhere along the line.  I've been building this thing all summer.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the following bot:

```
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "",
    appPassword: ""
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);  

bot.dialog('colors' , [function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which color?", "red|green|blue", 
            { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
    },
    function (session, results) {           
        session.send(`You chose: ${results.response.entity}.`); 
    }])
.triggerAction({matches: /^color/ })                       
.endConversationAction( "endColorChoice", "Ok, no color chosen.", 
            { matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^quit$|^nevermind$/i, 
            confirmPrompt: "This will abandon your choice. Are you sure?" } );

var server = restify.createServer();
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
server.listen(process.env.port || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});
```

Here are the results:

[image]

With a 'no' response:

[image]

Maybe if you share more of your bot's code, we can figure out what is going wrong.  Or, please post a simplified example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What happens when you answer "no" since that's what I was reporting.  "yes" works fine.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the flow with a 'no' response.

Comment: Cool.  I'll try your example.  My botbuilder's a little out of date, wondering if thats playing a part.  

I'll work with your simplified bot to test.   Thanks!